# Java security vulnerability for basic applet

Tags: java, security, browser, applet

I am a beginner in Java programming and I am practicing applets for the first time.  My first applet displays an error and I can't view the applet without clicking on a "act

I am a beginner in Java programming and I am practicing applets for the first time.  I'm trying to view my applet in my browser (firefox), but the web page displays a box containing the following message:

```
This plugin has security vulnerabilities.  
Click here to activate the Java(TM) Platform SE 7 U Plugin.
```

My question is:  What does this mean, why is it happening & how can & get rid of the box?  Does it mean that there is something wrong with my code?

Comment: What Java version is that?

Comment: whatever the newest 1 is

Comment: This might help you understand why the message came up.. http://www.us-cert.gov/cas/techalerts/TA13-010A.html (its nothing with your code, but with the Java Plugin running on the browser)

Comment: See [Disabled Java warning appearance & affect on Java Web Start apps](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14487698/418556) for a description of why the message is there, and what we can do about it (move to JWS).

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a problem with your code.  The Java plugin that runs applets within the browser has had some issues with security recently, and the folks that make Firefox decided to disable the plugin by default.  Just click the box and your applet should run.

Comment: After refreshing the page, the warning comes back.  Is there a way to keep it away for good?

Comment: I am not sure for Firefox, but try snooping around plugin settings. It may come up there for security notifications.

Comment: *"Is there a way to keep it away for good?"*  No.  Apart from Oracle issuing a JRE that has not got the bug, then convincing browser makers to remove the prompt - I don't like their chances of achieving the latter.

Answer (score 0):

there should be a little icon just west of the www in your address bar...click it>"activate all plugins" drop down menu click "always activate for this site"...stole this from another site....

https://service.parachat.com/knowledgebase/280/I-see-This-plugin-has-security-vulnerabilities-Click-here-to-activate-Java-display.html