# Java applet not working in firefox

Tags: java, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm sure this question has been solved, but I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for.  I'm trying to display an applet on firefox, but I can't get it to display with firefox warning me about security vulnerabilities.  I first started with Java SE 7.  I tried installing Java SE 6 to see if it would fix the problem, but that didn't work.  Could someone please help me resolve this problem?

Comment: See also [Disabled Java warning appearance & affect on Java Web Start apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487698/disabled-java-warning-appearance-affect-on-java-web-start-apps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that problem is related to the security issues in java SE 7 -7u10 jdk- (which because of it I had simular problems opening Java applications on different browsers)
http://www.csoonline.com/article/724327/oracle-s-java-security-update-lacking-experts-say

see also 
http://blog.mozilla.org/security/2013/01/11/protecting-users-against-java-vulnerability/

But I once made it work I think there's a small link somewhere so that you can proceed but take responsibility for your own actions !