# Java applet stopped working in Firefox, in IE it works fine

Tags: java, firefox, applet

My java applet stopped working in firefox, but it works fine in IE. Since there is increasing number of people having the same issue, I suppose the issue might have been caused by new java update.

I have checked the release notes and tried proposed workaround, but it didn't help.

All the applet does in Firefox is load and then immediatelly starts teardown, as you can see from the following log:

```
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
basic: Starting applet teardown
basic: Finished applet teardown
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@195f30
basic: PluginMain.unregisterApplet: 1 from mananger sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2Manager@1289261
```

Any ideas what might help here?

Comment: As the @MadProgrammer likes to say, Applet is a deprecated technology.  The day may come when it also stops working in IE (and the day may also come when no uses IE anymore).

Comment: It's more urgent than "the day may come." Support for plug-ins other than Flash has been or will be removed from Edge, Chrome, and Firefox *this year.* Your time would be best spent coming up with an alternative to the applet; plug-ins are a dead end.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this problem has various reasons. I am sharing some of them and giving some suggestion link to solve the issue. You have to make some try of them.

### Suggestion-1:

this warning isn't coming from firefox but from the java plugin itself - please [update your plugins](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/plugincheck/).

some more information about java's security settings are also available at oracle's support: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml

### Resource Link:

1. [How can I stop Firefox from blocking a Java applet from a site that
   I trust?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/963349)

### Suggestion-2:

**Remove stand-alone version of JavaFX (Windows)**

If you have JavaFX installed then

1. [Find and remove all versions of JavaFX](https://java.com/en/download/help/javafx_uninstall.xml) and Java through the Windows
   Uninstall Control Panel.
2. Run the [Microsoft uninstall utility](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall/en) to repair corrupted registry
   keys that prevents programs from being completely uninstalled or
   blocking new installations and updates.
3. [Reinstall Java](https://java.com/getjava/)

### Suggestion-3:

Older versions of the Java Deployment Toolkit (DT) and the Java Plugin have been disabled by Firefox. Some Java versions are flagged by Firefox as 'Add-ons may be causing problems'.

If Firefox thinks an add-on is unsafe and can cause a security risk, it will block it from loading. In case of a soft block Firefox will present a warning message but will allow the user to continue if they wish but with compromised security. In the case of a hard block Firefox will block installation so that the user cannot use this add-on. To resolve this, the user should update to latest version of Java.

### Workaround

Upgrading to the latest Java 7 version should resolve the issue. If you see the warning message, follow these steps:

1. Ensure that the Disable box is checked.
2. Click on Restart Firefox.
3. Download the latest version of Java..

### Resource Link:

1. [Firefox warning message: Add-ons may be causing problems](https://java.com/en/download/help/firefox_java.xml)

### Suggestion-4:

There are 2 links for java applet issue for firefox and solvency. You can go through:

1. [I can't run applet on my firefox browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/407659/i-cant-run-applet-on-my-firefox-browser)
2. [Java applet not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615584/java-applet-not-working-in-firefox)

Answer (score 2):

firefox is not providing support to applet plug-in.See link https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-java-plugin-to-view-interactive-content

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you are using java 7/8. Have you checked following link of mozilla. 
https://java.com/en/download/help/firefox_java.xml. As applet works as a plugin, this option would help.

Comment: Nope, this didn't help :/

Answer (score 1):

Update your firefox settings to allow applets, update correct java plugins and permissions inside firefox. Mostly applet not loading issue seems to be permission related.