# Sign applet and deploy it in intranet

Tags: java, security, browser, web, signed-applet

i wrote a web application which is used in our intranet. I alswo wrote a small Java Applet to integrate with our windows desktops (opening applications and files). Of course i get a security warning everytime i access my web application.
I've read on stackoverflow that it should be possible, to sign my applet and roll out the certificate to all my clients (Windows XP and Windows 7) to get rid of the securitywarning.

Is there a tutorial how to do that? Can i do that without purchasing a expensive certificate because i'm only using this application in my intranet?

Thx for any information and best regards!

Comment: What warning, ***exactly***?  E.G. see[1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14659057/418556) & [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14487698/418556).

Comment: Is your applet already signed?

Comment: I've signed it with a self signed certificate some month ago. It shows a yellow warning sign and asks like "Do you want to execute this application?" (my clients are in german, so i dont know the exact english phrase).
Edit:
The messages looks like this: http://forums.whatthetech.com/index.php?showtopic=124743

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution here: http://wikigu.blogspot.co.at/2011/06/signing-java-applet-with-your-own-ca.html

The last step is to install the generated crt (in the example it's the "server.crt") file into the Trusted Publishers certificate store.

Edit: i just realized that it is just working in Internet Explorer (applet is executed without any warning or dialogue) but not in Firefox. Firefox still shows a security warning. Does anybody know how to get rid of the warning in Firefox?